# Ruby Inserting "\n" newline into String with Regular Expression

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a variable like so:

> output =  "KORD 142327Z 1500/1606 31012KT P6SM FEW060 SCT300 FM150200 04007KT >P6SM FEW300 FM150400 01005KT P6SM SKC FM151400 22008KT P6SM SCT250 FM151900 >22014G23KT P6SM BKN250 FM160200 23014KT P6SM SCT150 BKN250 WS010/25040"

I want to insert a newline before every "FM" character sequence so I can print it to user and its easier to read.

Currently my code is as follows, but replaces the first "FM" sequence with a "\n" then stops without continuing onto the next "FM" set.

> output [/(FM{1})/, 0]  = "\n"

I don't want to replace FM with newline. I need to append "\n" immediately before each "FM" character set. Any help with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 output.gsub!("FM","\nFM")
```

Comment: Make that output.gsub!("FM","\nFM")

Comment: that would replace FM with a new line. I don't want to replace FM. Just put a new line before every occurrence of FM

Comment: If `"FM"` is only to be converted to `"\nFM"` when `"F"` is immediately preceded by a word boundary, change `"FM"` to `/\bFM/`. That will prevent, say, "'IFM'" from being converted to `"I\nFM"`.

Comment: Thanks Cary. When you say word Boundary, do you mean a character? Having characters prior to `"F"` is not my situation, but I will keep this in mind if a similar situation comes up.